# How do I display fields of other models in a create view in Django?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I'm trying to create some entries in the database. I am not able to input anything for the Address models. I would like to be able to add the individual fields of the shipping_address. How can I achieve this?

### serializer

```
class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    """Serializer for the users object"""

    class Meta:
        model = get_user_model()
        fields = ('email', 'password', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'mailing_address', 'shipping_address', 'phone', 'is_active', 'is_staff', 'is_approver')

    def create(self, validated_data):
        """Create a new user with encrypted password and return it"""
        return get_user_model().objects.create_user(**validated_data)
```

### models

```
   class Address(models.Model):
        first_address = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, default='')
        second_address = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, default='')
        city = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, default='')
        state = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, default='')
        zip = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, default='')
    
    
    class Phone(models.Model):
        phone_number = PhoneField(blank=True, help_text='Contact phone number')
    
    
    class ShippingAddress(models.Model):
        first_address = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, default='')
        second_address = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, default='')
        city = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, default='')
        state = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, default='')
        zip = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, default='')
    
    
    class User(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):
        """Custom user model that suppors using email instead of username"""
        email = models.EmailField(max_length=255, unique=True)
        first_name = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, default='')
        last_name = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, default='')
        password = forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput)
        phone = models.ForeignKey(Phone, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True)
        mailing_address = models.ForeignKey(Address, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True)
        shipping_address = models.ForeignKey(ShippingAddress, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True)
        is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
        is_staff = models.BooleanField(default=False)
        is_approver = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    
        objects = UserManager()
    
        USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
```

[image]

Comment: This is a good question...and I don't have an answer in the context of DRF. However, one observation: why do you have `Address` and `ShippingAddress` models that have the exact same fields? Instead, you can just keep `Address` and use it for all addresses in the `User` model.

Comment: my intention is that a user can have different billing, and shipping addresses. and they can have multiple addresses.

Comment: That completely makes sense. The difference between a billing and shipping address is the name of the field on the `User` model. There is no need for separate `BillingAddress` and `ShippingAddress` models. A single `Address` model for both `billing_address` and `shipping_address` fields will suffice, and in fact make your app much simpler.

Comment: See my edited answer. You may need to refresh the page. To emphasize: the screenshot that you show in your question here IS A DEVELOPMENT TOOL ONLY. Users of your web app should NEVER see this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you can use DRF's [writable nested serializer](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations/#writable-nested-serializers).

Something like these (haven't tested it yet):

- Add a serializer for the `Address` model:

  ```py
  class AddressSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
      class Meta:
          model = Address
          fields = '__all__'
  ```
- And modify your current serializer for the `User` model (just like @Code-Apprentice said the comment, you can use the same `Address` model for both `mailing_address` and `shipping_address`):

  ```py
  class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
      """Serializer for the users object"""
      mailing_address = AddressSerializer()
      shipping_address = AddressSerializer()

      class Meta:
          model = get_user_model()
          fields = ('email', 'password', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'mailing_address', 'shipping_address', 'phone', 'is_active', 'is_staff', 'is_approver')

      def create(self, validated_data):
          """Create a new user with encrypted password and return it""" 
          mailing_address = Address.objects.create(**validated_data.pop('mailing_address'))
          shipping_address = Address.objects.create(**validated_data.pop('shipping_address'))
          return get_user_model().objects.create_user(mailing_address=mailing_address, shipping_address=shipping_address, **validated_data)
  ```

Answer (score 1):

> How do I display fields of other models in a create view in Django?

One thing to be careful about here: Django Rest Framework provides a convenient Web interface to interact with the REST API you are building. However, this is not the only way, and probably not even the most common way, to interact with your API.

In fact, users of your app, SHOULD NOT SEE THIS WEB INTERFACE. Instead, you should build your own interface which interacts with your REST API. This gives you the flexibility to create whatever forms in HTML that you want.

For example, you can create a single form with all of the user fields along with fields for a shipping address and for a separate billing address. Then you write JavaScript in the front end to create the `Address` objects with POST requests to your API. The POST request will return an id of the new address object. Then you make another POST request to create a user, with that `id` and all of the other user fields.

On a side note, there is no need for a `ShippingAddress` model which has the exact same fields as your `Address` model. Just use `Address` for all address fields:

```
        mailing_address = models.ForeignKey(Address, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True)
        shipping_address = models.ForeignKey(Address, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True)
```